# Cannot find symbol class on Butter Knife generated code

Tags: android, butterknife

I'm trying to use butter knife but having trouble with the generated code. It's complaining with a namespace... I don't know why.

> error: cannot find symbol class Detail

To simplify see all peaces, I take a print. Can you help me?

[image]

- com.phormar.android.Detail namespace exists;
- PessoaFragment are on com.phormar.android.Detail package as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it just renaming the namespace Detail to detail (lower case), and all start to work again. My conclusion is that cannot have a upper case on namespace where Butter Knife are being used.

Comment: Thanks, i had the same issue! this helped me a ton!!

Answer (score 17):

Make sure the version of the ButterKnife library matches the apt plugin version like this:

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'

apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
```

Please follow this link while adding ButterKnife to your *build.gradle* file:

https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife

Comment: Yes! This is the correct answer! No need to change namespace to lowercase. Just use the latest version of ButterKnife. Thanks for saving my time :)